# Easytouse Android app to visualise offline maps

Tags: android, mbtiles, offline

I need to propose an application android, ultrasimple of use which proposes to visualize various layers offline (french Scan25, Orthophoto). The idea would be to create mbtiles (with QGIS, Mobac, Mapcache, or equivalent) and prepare it for each employee, a file that corresponds to its intervention department, knowing that it must be 100% offline.

Do you have one (or more) applications to recommend that respond to that? The employees for some are novices in computer science, and it would have to be hypersimple to use (OruxMaps, Osmand, Qfield, etc.) offer too much.
Here, we would just like to offer the display of these funds, possibly choose the layers / transparencies, focus on the position of the GPS, possibly register a GPS point and that's it.

The better would be that we can offer a link to each employee who can recover the application and the file that contains the data (mbtiles format or equivalent), if possible free / not paid because there are many people to equip .

Would anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Avenza PDF maps is a free Android and iOS application that allows you to view your location using the mobile device's location services via a geospatial PDF or geospatial TIFF.

It is easy to create the geospatial PDF using ArcGIS10.x.  Just export your map layout to PDF - but not before selecting the advanced tab - and clicking export geospatial information.

QGIS can export a print composer map to geospatial TIFF and you can either add that to Avenza or take the time to use the Raster - Translate tools to convert the TIFF to PDF for a smaller file size and faster rendering.

I think the free version of Avenza allows you to add five maps, and unlimited maps with a paid subscription.  The maps are stored on the device so you do not depend on a cellular or WiFi connection to view your location on the map.  The application is simple to use.  Avenza does not care which of the three popular coordinate reference systems I generate maps in.

The downside is you are just viewing your location on the static map so any data would need to be displayed or labeled since you cannot query the data in Avenza.